# Comparing Equity Funds

Tags: equities

I am trying to compare 2 equity funds, I have 10Y of monthly returns (no knowledge of their share allocations) - and their index benchmark returns.

They are both Value managers but I am not looking for qualitative comparisons. Are there any clever/interesting ways of going about doing this comparison that you may know of, aside from showing the usual YTD, MTD, 1Y,2Y returns and Sharpe ratio, drawdowns,...

-Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most literature focus on comparing fund returns using a model alpha. A good overview is: [Cahart (1997)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1997.tb03808.x/pdf) and [Berk and Binsbergen (2015)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304405X15000628).
Basically you regress the fund returns on most common used factors (market return, HML, SMB, Liquidity and Momentum factors) and compare alphas after fees.